# How can I specify a short caption for a listing?

Tags: listings, captions, optional-arguments

One of my listings has a very long name. In the `\lstlistoflistings` table of contents, I would just like to have a shortened version of it. How can I specify an abbreviated name for my listing?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage[font={color=ocre,bf},figurename=Fig.,labelfont={it}]{caption}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
% create a file for output
!touch testFile.txt
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
\end{filecontents*}

\newfontfamily{\lstconsolas}{Consolas}

\newcommand\ph\mlplaceholder

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Matlab Algorithm}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of \lstlistingname s}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\lstconsolas,caption=Sample code from Matlab with a very very very very very loooooooooooooooong name]{sample.m}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\lstconsolas\small,
  escapechar=`,
  caption={For educational purposes},
]
% example of while loop using placeholders
while x2 = 1 + 100 `\ph{condition}`
  if `\ph{something-bad-happens}`
    break
  else
    % do something useful
  end
  % do more things
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The LoL should just show the `caption`, no "long Mathlab names" whatsoever. And I get no `matlab-prettifier.sty` in my TeXlive installation, so this is not reproduceable for me.

Comment: @vonbrand `matlab-prettifier` is available in TeX Live, but you may have to install it using the TeX Live Utility package manager.

Comment: You control what goes in the list of listings via the `caption` key, so what is the problem, exactly?

Comment: I wanted to have a shortened version of the caption verbiage to display in the LoL.  Similar to the way it is done for a "figure" caption...you define the figure caption (for example) as `{\includegraphics{Pictures/fig2}} \caption[Basic feedback control loop]{
Basic feedback control loop with a much longer name shown just below the figure.}`

Comment: @Joe I believe all captions use the same mechanism

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`listings`' `caption` key allows you to use the same syntax as

```
\caption[short title]{long title}
```

but you have to wrap braces around the value that you pass to the `caption` key, in order to "hide" the closing bracket that comes after the optional short-title argument:

```
\lstinputlisting[
    % ...
    caption = {[Short and sweet!]Sample code from Matlab with a very very very very very loooooooooooooooong name},
]{sample.m}
```

[image]